# When does com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent, billing

I'm `implementing` a feature related to `Android billing` but a receiver for `com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED` is required though.

There is not enough documentation for it so I will ask you -

When is an `intent` for this action broadcasted?

Comment: I have the same question. PURCHASES_UPDATED broadcast cannot be received if I redeemed a promo code from within the play store app while the app is running in the background. Could you share more information about the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This intent is triggered when a purchase is made outside of the app, *while* the app is running.

This is the way to detect when a [promo code](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime#implement_a_promotion) was redeemed through Google Play. However, keep in mind that this is only triggered when the app is running on the same device, so if you want to test this, you have to set split screen, have your app on one half of the screen, and Google Play on the other half, where you redeem your promo code.